# Imacros Regular Expression, Is what I'm asking too complex?

Tags: regex, screen-scraping, imacros

I'm trying to extract player names for upcoming tennis matches with IMACROS to later analyse in excel.

The site I want to take the player names from generates extra information that I do not want.

Horacio Zeballos  (ARG)
Joao Sousa  (PRT) 
Victor Estrella Burgos  (DOM) SE

Tommy Robredo  (ESP) PR
Fabio Fognini  (ITA) LL

Albert Ramos-Vinolas  (ESP) 5
Guido Pella  (ARG)
Leonardo Mayer  (ARG) WC

When I use the below extraction tag i get the extra info I don't need.

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:player-name EXTRACT=TXT

I'm not good with regex and don't know how to write an expression to remove all data after "(" and delete the trailing space to just leave me with the player name.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: `/^[^(]+\b/` should work in most regex flavors

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove extra info in the following way:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:player-name EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/ \\(.+/gm, '');")
```